# Multiple Publisher for Publish Subscribe java

Tags: java, xmpp, publish-subscribe, smack

1. try after my question was marked as not real question.

Here is what i am trying to do:

1. i create a node with a open Accessmodel with a user called "server" as Example

   `

   ```
   ConfigureForm form = new ConfigureForm(FormType.submit);
   form.setPersistentItems(false);

   form.setDeliverPayloads(true);
   form.setAccessModel(AccessModel.open);
   MyNode = (LeafNode) manager.createNode(nodeName);`
   ```
2. i use another user called.. "test". i get the node and i am trying to add a payloaditem with content

   ```
           try {


               myNode = (LeafNode) manager.getNode(nodeName);


               System.out.println("works");
           } catch (XMPPException e) {
               System.out.println("works not");
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           SimplePayload payload = new SimplePayload("session",
                   "pubsub:NewNode:session",
                   "<sessionId>testcontent</sessionId>");

           // putting null for id means you let server generate id
           PayloadItem<SimplePayload> item = new PayloadItem<SimplePayload>(null, payload);



               myNode.publish(item);
   ```

So.. when i publish the node there is no item connected to the node (as both user). when i use myNode.send(item); i'm not able to use send when i am the user "test" because this user didnt create the node. The result would be a forbidden(403) error.
I am thinking that maybe the problem is, that publish() is an async call..

Does anyone know a solution for this? or another way?

Comment: I did a "Workaround" just getting the message and delete the node.. isnt a good way but it works for me...

Comment: I can only infer that you are using smack. Maybe you should add this (important) information too.

Comment: It is still difficult to understand what your actual problem is.  You say you publish, but there is no item connected to the node.  How do you know this?  Also not sure why you have a problem with send vs. publish.  They both do the same thing, the send simply blocks while waiting for the reply while the publish simply ignores it.